# ldap_url: and ldap_master_url cannot be the same on an ldap replica

Tags: ldap, zimbra, postfix-mta

So i tried adding rt-mailgate in zimbra using the following tutorial http://muru-techsolution.blogspot.co.ke/2015/03/install-rt-mailgate-in-zimbra.html .but now when i try to restart zimbra services i get the following error:

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmcontrol start
 Host localhost
 Unable to determine enabled services from ldap.
 Enabled services read from cache. Service list may be inaccurate.
     Starting ldap...Done.
 Failed.
 ldap_url and ldap_master_url cannot be the same on an ldap replica
```

Am running the following version of zimbra:

```
Release 8.0.7_GA_6021.RHEL6_64_20140408123911 RHEL6_64 FOSS edition.
```

On linux version:

```
Linux x.domain.com 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 13 22:55:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Anyone come across the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a permissions related issue.
In general, this occurs after you changed some configurations as root user, instead of doing it as zimbra user.

To fix it, please do the following:

. As root, run:
   /opt/zimbra/libexec/zmfixperms

. restart your zimbra service:
  service zimbra restart

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Erick, it was really a permissions issue. I inadvertently run the "zmlocalconfig" command as root user instead of zimbra user. This overwrote the localconfig.xml file. I was then able to locate a backup copy of the file and the zimbra services restarted successfully. Also the integration with rt-mailgate worked, after i ranthe command again but as zimbra user. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, if you don't mind, please accept the answer as the solution to your problem, so others will benefit from the information.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, `/opt/zimbra/conf/localconfig.xml` got mostly empty and that was causing the error. Restoring it from backup fixed the problem.

Comment: just fried a whole server when our baseline config uninstalled resolvconf (since, unfortunately this is an ubuntu host, it via dependencies uninstalled almost the whole zimbra install..), your reply saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Zimbra 9 from Zextra and got the same error. I solved it following this [article](https://community.zextras.com/forum/zimbra-ose-howto/error-openssl-pkcs12-export-to-opt-zimbra-ssl-zimbra-jetty-pkcs12-failed1/):

> 1 - use screen to install Zimbra 9. You'll need two screens to do
> this. If you are not familiar with screen you may use tmux or just
> login twice on the server you're going to install it;
>
> 2 - on one screen start the installation process as always til you get
> to to the "apply" moment, right after you set the admin password;
>
> 3 - on the second screen edit /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcertmgr file, go to
> the line 1817, and add the option "-nomac" to the @out array, like
> this:
>
> ```
>   @out = $self->run(
>         $self->Openssl, "pkcs12", "-inkey", $keyf,
>         "-in",          $crtf,    "-name",  $server,
>         "-export",      "-out",   $pkcsf,   "-passout",
>         "pass:$kpass",  "-nomac", "2>&1"
>     );
> ```
>
> 4 - go to the line 1878 and do the very same adding "-nomac" to @out
> array and save the file
>
> 5 - get back to the first screen and "apply"...